# page.keyboard.down("Control") is not working on mac m1

Tags: javascript, node.js, automation, automated-tests, puppeteer

```
.then(function(){
    return page.keyboard.down('Control')
})
.then(function(){
    return page.keyboard.press('A',{delay:100})
})
.then(function(){
    return page.keyboard.press('V',{delay:100})
})
.then(function(){
    return page.keyboard.up('Control')
})
```

I've tried `page.evaluate( () => document.execCommand( 'selectall', false, null ) );` and it works. But how to cut and paste after that?

Comment: page.keyboard.press("X") for cut doesn't work after that evaluate method? Because it was not selected and it prints "X"